# QueryDslPredicateExecutor not found in spring data commons 2.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I spent hours to find QueryDslPredicateExecutor in spring data. Why it is called
QueryDslPredicateExecutor in docs an blogs but ***QuerydslPredicateExecutor*** (small D!) in artifact 2.0.4.RELEASE? In which versions it is correct?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It renamed from `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` to `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` in 2.x.

see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/9c6f764131ab27b5d81e3f84c028965803afa6b9